# Empty response from post request to https url

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, https

I am trying to get response from my server using Post method, which works well if the server has a http address. However if I try to get response from a similar server which has an https URL, I get an empty response.
When I check the logs from my server, I see the request did not reach the server at ALL. I am using sockets to connect to server. I am not sure what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include "httpRequest.h"
#include <windows.h>   

// Following code is in main()

// Code to connect to server (port used 443) which return succesfully.
SOCKET socket = connectToServer(strIp);

// returns me size of request
int iResult = send(socket , request.toString().c_str(), requestLength - iSent, 0 );

// This returns me 0 always for https server url
// I tried MSG_WAITALL\0 but results are same
char buffer[10054];
iResult = recv(socket , buffer, 10054, MSG_WAITALL);

// This too always returns 0 indicating no error.
int Err = WSAGetLastError();
```

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one of them. The code is not valid C, but is slightly more valid in C++. Won't compile in either, though.

Comment: Where do you encrypt the message?

Comment: I don't encrypt it. I doing this for the first time, I assumed it would be encrypted automatically. Apologies if this might sound stupid. Is there any specific algorithm I need to encrypt the request with?

Comment: HTTPS is HTTP on top of an encrypted communication layer (SSL/TLS). Most people use OpenSSL for the underlying layer. Use [WinInet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384322(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of raw sockets.